# How can I find out if all my contrib modules are compatible with the latest core version?

Tags: 10

I have quite a number of Drupal modules on my Drupal 9 website and I want to update my Drupal core to the latest, but I'm not sure if this would break the entire site if one of the modules isn't compatible with the latest core version.

I can go to each module page individually to check, but is there a quick command in the CLI to find out? `drush pm-list` doesn't really seem to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by "latest core version" you mean moving from one major version to another (for example, 9 to 10), you can use the [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module.

In addition to telling you whether each contrib module is compatible with the new version, you can scan your custom modules and contrib modules to look for compatibility issues.

You can use Upgrade Status from drush, too:

`drush upgrade_status:analyze`

Comment: i really don't want to add more modules if possible. thx tho.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Upgrade Status is not a module you leave installed.  Instead, it's something you add to your local dev environment, run the checks, and then remove once everything is good.  (Until you need to check again on the next major version.). It should not be installed on production.  So this is not a module that you have to worry about causing overhead for your site.

Answer (score -1):

You can install Drupal Rector which can save you a lot of manual work by automating code upgrades to Drupal 10. Run the following command from the project root directory:

```
composer require --dev palantirnet/drupal-rector
```

Here is the official documentation about Drupal Rector: https://www.drupal.org/project/rector

While Drupal Rector has very good transformation coverage for deprecated APIs, the results should not be considered complete. For the Drupal Rector UI version, you can also download [Upgrade Rector](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_rector) module.